# SVD on Large and Sparse Matrix (24 x 4G) on R

Tags: r, matrix, sparse-matrix, svd, large-data

I have to SVD on a very large matrix(24 x 2^32) on R. This matrix is less than 0.01% sparse. I could store this matrix by using `simple_sparse_array` class in `slam` package.

At first, I tried to use `sparseMatrix`(in `Matrix` package) and `irlba`.
I could compute SVD on 60k x 60k matrix by using this.

Unfortunately,It seems `sparseMatrix` cannot store this huge matrix.

```
sparseMatrix(i=1,j=1,x=1,dims=c(24,2^32))
#Error in if (any(Dim < 0)) return("Dim slot must contain non-negative values") :
#missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
#In addition: Warning message:
#In sparseMatrix(i = 1, j = 1, x = 1, dims = c(24, 2^32)) :
#NAs introduced by coercion
```

I can use 750G RAM for a week in maximum. What is the best solution?

Comment: In `sparseMatrix` the number of rows or columns must be an integer; your 2^32 exceeds  `.Machine$integer.max`, which is 2^31-1. Can't you resize your matrix? It's seem so strange to have such a huge number of columns compared to just 24 rows.

Comment: Yeah..,I tried to rearrange my (silly) matrix, but I cannot.  So I'm trying to reduce size of matrix by putting together raw data, or using other simple matrix factorization methods (like CUR).